# Why should xercesImpl bring its own XML APIs to my maven project while all XML APIs are in rt.jar?

Tags: java, maven, xerces

When I add xercesImpl-2.9.1 to my maven project's pom xml-apis-1.3.04.jar gets into my project assembly as a xercesImpl-2.9.1's compile scope dependency.
xml-apis-1.3.04 contains javax.xml.*, org.w3c.dom.* and org.sax.xml.*. 
What for? All of these APIs are provided by rt.jar (since 1.5 at least). 
A typical standalone application will ignore xml-apis-1.3.04.jar and load XML API classes from rt.jar anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably for backwards compatibility for older JREs (yeah, I know no-one sane would still be using them, but just check out the number of questions about Java 1.4.2).